Derived attributes in Rails 7
Following my recent question on this subject, one suggestion was to use a database generated field, which I think is the best solution. However, I couldn't find much in the way of references or examples in my search. It seems that SQLite itself supports generated columns (SQLite docs) but I couldn't find any reference in the sqlite gem docs: this link {https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/sqlite3/1.3.11/SQLite3/Constants/ColumnType} leads nowhere.
I found this example by Mintbit but when I ran the same syntax in a test migration, the schema had this error message:
# Could not dump table "test_virtuals" because of following StandardError
#   Unknown type 'virtual' for column 'full_name'

Can anyone guide me as to what should be done for database generated fields?
I'm running rails (7.0.8.4), is that the issue?

Are you planning on deploying with SQLite as well?

Hey @max probably not. I will have to check if Postgres can do it as well I guess.

If you're deploying to Postgres you should dev/test on Postgres so that you don't get nasty suprises. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html

I agree @max but when I tried to upgrade Postgres on my Mac, I made a complete hash of it. I tried everything, and ended up deleting every file under every directory that smelt like it had seen pg in the name, but when I installed pg again it said my database is not compatible. What database? This was some time ago, I still haven't worked up the courage to look at it again.

that's a problem you're going to have to fix sooner or later. When I was using Macs I always just used Postgres.app. If you need a specific version of Postgres you can use Docker. I really don't suggest you take the approach in the accepted answer as that will just blow up later when you're trying to run the same migration in production.

Support for virtual columns in SQLite3 was added in Rails 7.2, and isn't available in earlier versions.
In the changelog for ActiveRecord 7.2:

Add support for generated columns to the SQLite3 adapter.
Generated columns (both stored and dynamic) are supported since version 3.31.0 of SQLite. This adds support for those to the SQLite3 adapter.
create_table :users do |t|
  t.string :name
  t.virtual :name_upper, type: :string, as: 'UPPER(name)'
  t.virtual :name_lower, type: :string, as: 'LOWER(name)', stored: true
end



This is a pretty tempory fix though as it will only work if you're using SQLite in production.

It looks like Postgres 17 supports generated columns: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html. Not sure about the rails pg gem. More work ahead!

The pg gem is actually completely separate from Rails. ActiveRecord has an adapter layer that interfaces with all the different database driver gems.
